# Организация виртуальной машины на ПК.

Tags: windows, virtualbox

Здравствуйте.
Я пытаюсь создать у себя на компьютере виртуальную машину, используя VirtualBox для 32-битных систем семейства Windows. У меня стоит Win7 Home Basic 32bit(простоватая).
Когда я запускаю пакет установки, то вроде бы все устанавливается нормально, затем программа просит установить Oracle`овские драйвера для сетевой платы, USB и т.д.
Так вот, когда я эти драйвера все до единого устанавливаю, то после перезагрузки системы - 
фатальная ошибка, "синий экран смерти" и рестарт ПК. А вот когда отказываюсь от установки дров, то все фатальной ошибки после перезагрузки системы не возникает, но(!) VirtualBox не работает.....что мне делать, подскажите пожалуйста. =)

---

Вроде бы все системы, которые я устанавливаю на виртуалку работают, но после перезагрузки моей основной системы приходится делать откат, так как выдается ошибка(описано выше).

Comment: Процессор у Вас какой ?

У меня на 64-бит Windows 7 и 32-bit XP SP3 проблем не возникало. Поставил на VirtualBox ubuntu. 

Правда, USB и прочую периферию я в конфигурацию не включал, даже CD/DVD виртуально (образ ОС) (а собственно зачем они на виртуалке ?)

Сеть: оставил контроллер, который VirtualBox предлагает по умолчанию (по моему он виртуальный, не та карта, что в компе стоит), тип подключения установил **сетевой мост** (на загрузку не влияло, а для связи по сети с хостом важно).

Для переноса данных сконфигурил "общие папки".

Comment: @Palmervan, задайте вопрос там и посмотрите, через сколько минут на него кто-нибудь отреагирует.

Comment: У меня на виртуалке тоже запускаются системы типа Ubuntu 11.10 и Linux Mint, правда после перезагрузки компьютера - беда! Приходится все откатывать. Может программа создает какой-то виртуальный поток, который не может работать нормально вместе с основным.

Comment: [Производитель](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#idp7547360) ничего об ограничениях на Home Basic 32bit не пишет.

А что значит "VirtualBox не работает" ? ОС не грузится ? Ставится из дистрибутива нормально, а при первой перезагрузке зависает ?

Опишите поподробнее, что Вы делаете и что видите.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, все потому, что на основной машине стоит `Home Basic`, "домашняя" версия, *не полноценная*. Разрядность системы, думаю, тут не причем.

Comment: Разрядность IMHO связана с возможностью поставить 64-bit OS на виртуалку. 

Вообще же проблема может быть в отсутствии команд аппаратной виртуализации (VT-x) у процессора.

Comment: Я просто установил виртуалку, затем перезагрузил комп. И синий экран смерти!

Comment: @Asen, при установке приняли все по умолчанию (next -> next -> ... finish) и потом "синий экран" ?

Comment: Да, но, как писал выше, синий экран только после установки оракловских драйверов.

Comment: Под разрядностью имел ввиду работоспособность вообще, не ограничения. Вопрос задан о синем экране.  
Из-за процессора, не знаю... `VirtualBox` наверное все же смотрит, на какое железо устанавливается.

Comment: А вы дрова устанавливаете какие? вин7-ские? Попробуйте скачать новые дрова.

Comment: Поддерживаю @Ёхарный Бабай.

Answer (score 0):

предполагаю нужно [логи](https://hyperhost.ua/info/ru/kak-posmotret-logi-windows#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%E2%80%9C%20Win%2BR,%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F.) посмотреть виндовые, на что конкретно она жалуется, виртуализация включена в биосе?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/751262)